# Mapfile errors, unable to access my shapefiles

Tags: mapserver

I am getting the following errors in my mapfile

```
[Thu Oct  3 11:40:23 2019].299949 msWMSLoadGetMapParams(): enabling non-square pixels.
[Thu Oct  3 11:40:23 2019].303483 msDrawMap(): kicking into non-square pixel preserving mode.
[Thu Oct  3 11:40:23 2019].303495 msDrawMap(): rendering using outputformat named png (AGG/PNG).
[Thu Oct  3 11:40:23 2019].303499 msDrawMap(): WMS/WFS set-up and query, 0.000s
[Thu Oct  3 11:40:23 2019].303563 msShapefileOpen(): Unable to access file. (/usr/local/var/www/data/ne_10m_admin_0_countries/ne_10m_admin_0_countries)
[Thu Oct  3 11:40:23 2019].303615 msShapefileOpen(): Unable to access file. (/usr/local/var/www/data/ne_10m_admin_0_countries)
[Thu Oct  3 11:40:23 2019].303624 msDrawMap(): Image handling error. Failed to draw layer named 'Countries'.
[Thu Oct  3 11:40:23 2019].303682 mapserv request processing time (msLoadMap not incl.): 0.004s
[Thu Oct  3 11:40:23 2019].303690 msFreeMap(): freeing map at 0x7ffd85006000.
```

The mapfile is really simple

```
MAP
  NAME "MAPSERVER QUICKSTART"
  EXTENT -137 29 -53 88
  UNITS DD
  SHAPEPATH "/usr/local/var/www/data/ne_10m_admin_0_countries"
  SIZE 800 600
  CONFIG "MS_ERRORFILE" "/tmp/ms_error.txt"
  DEBUG 5
  IMAGETYPE PNG24

  PROJECTION
    "init=epsg:4326"
  END

  WEB
    METADATA
      ows_enable_request "*"
    END
  END

  LAYER
    NAME "Countries"
    GROUP "default"
    STATUS ON
    TYPE POLYGON
    DATA "ne_10m_admin_0_countries"
    CLASS
      STYLE
        COLOR 246 241 223
        OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
      END
    END
  END

END
```

Then when I list the contents of the directory I get this

```
ls -latr /usr/local/var/www/data/ne_10m_admin_0_countries
total 18448
-rw-r--r--@ 1 tommie  staff     2140 May 21  2018 ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shx
-rw-r--r--@ 1 tommie  staff  8800376 May 21  2018 ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp
-rw-r--r--@ 1 tommie  staff      147 May 21  2018 ne_10m_admin_0_countries.prj
-rw-r--r--@ 1 tommie  staff   599487 May 21  2018 ne_10m_admin_0_countries.dbf
-rw-r--r--@ 1 tommie  staff        5 May 21  2018 ne_10m_admin_0_countries.cpg
-rw-r--r--@ 1 tommie  staff        7 May 21  2018 ne_10m_admin_0_countries.VERSION.txt
-rw-r--r--@ 1 tommie  staff    24083 May 21  2018 ne_10m_admin_0_countries.README.html
drwxr--r--@ 9 tommie  staff      288 Oct  3 11:03 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 tommie  admin      128 Oct  3 11:44 ..
```

Why would it be unable to access my files.

Comment: I think it should work like you have it, but try still with `DATA "ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp"`

Comment: Yeah I tried that too. And still the same error.

Comment: Is mapserv running as tommie

Comment: What user is the web server (Apache?) running as? Who is the owner of the `/usr/local/var/www` directory?